# Помогите программно подключатся к VPN в Android

Tags: android-studio, openvpn

Покажите и расскажите как подключать VPN на андроиде программно. Работаю в Android Studio. Перелопатил много инфы в инете - ничего понятного не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста.